# Colorful marbles

Tags: statistics

Ok so I'm having some work samples at school soon and I'm trying to practice my statistics and probability. I was given a problem with marbles. Ok.. So there are 3 red marbles, 5 greens marbles, and 2 blue marbles. A student is given a chance to pick out 2 marbles when they are picked the student only puts 1 marble back. What is the probability of picking out 2 blues marbles in a row? Help!?

Comment: So, he pics 2 out, one at time, and he puts one of them back after he picks it. Which one does he put back?

Comment: @JohnJPershing Perhaps randomly 50-50 coin flip.

Comment: The question didn't say Which marbles he pick out?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Note that picking two and putting one back (randomly) is exactly the same that picking one, provided that in the bag there are al least two marbles left